# Wordpress site SQL query to get <optgroup> set to distinct value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Example table data

```
id  manufacturer  yeast_name  yeast_id  archived
01  Bootleg       American    BL001     yes
02  Imperial      American    IMP001    yes
03  Imperial      German      IMP002    yes
04  White Labs    Chico       WLP001    yes
05  White Labs    London Ale  WLP488    yes
06  White Labs    Lager       WLP893    no
07  Wyeast        American    WY1056    yes
```

I am attempting to get distinct `<optgroup>` to output on my Wordpress site using code snippets.  I was able to do it on a non wordpress site using this code:

WORKING CODE

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_name WHERE archived = "yes" ORDER BY yeast_id ASC';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo '<select class="req" id="strain" name="strain" size="1" style="width:40%;">';
echo '<option value="#">Choose Yeast Strain...</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array[$row['manufacturer']][] = $row;
}

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        echo "<optgroup label='".$key."'>";
        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
            echo "<option value='".$v['yeast_id']."-".$v['yeast_name']."'>".$v['yeast_id']." ".$v['yeast_name']."</option>";
        }
    echo "</optgroup>";
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

I am running into issues using the $wpdb->get_results for Wordpress, but I am failing.  I put the results into an array using 'ARRAY_A'.  I am stuck on how to do the "while" portion of the code.  Any help would be outstanding.

NON WORKING CODE

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wpog_user_yeast WHERE archived = 'yes' ORDER BY yeast_id ASC", ARRAY_A);

echo '<select class="req" id="strain" name="strain" size="1" style="width:40%;">';
echo '<option value="#">Choose Yeast Strain...</option>';
while($row = $wpdb->get_results($results)){
  $array[$row[$results->manufacturer]][] =$row;
}
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        echo "<optgroup label='".$key."'>";
        echo "</optgroup>";
    }
}

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Pls show the code that does not work, ckearly highilighting the oarts where you struggle! Distinct is pointless if you include the id column in the resultset, since that is unique for each record. Pls add the code as an edit in the question!

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

$result is already an array, so that `$wpdb->get_results($results)`should give you an error
use

```
foreach($results as $row){
 $array[$row[$results->manufacturer]][] =$row;
}
```

Also you should keep the `$table = $wpdb->prefix ."user_yeast"` in case you want to use the code also on another wopress site

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @nbk.  Your solution got me 95% of the way there!  A little tweak got me the rest of the way.

`$array[$row['manufacturer']][] =$row;` worked instead of your code.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wpog_user_yeast WHERE archived = 'yes' ORDER BY yeast_id ASC", ARRAY_A);
echo '<select class="req" id="strain" name="strain" size="1" style="width:40%;">';
echo '<option value="#">Choose Yeast Strain...</option>';
foreach($results as $row){
  $array[$row['manufacturer']][] =$row;
}
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        echo "<optgroup label='".$key."'>";
        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
            echo "<option value='".$v['yeast_id']."-".$v['yeast_name']."'>".$v['yeast_id']." ".$v['yeast_name']."</option>";
        }
    echo "</optgroup>";
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```